# Short syntax to display all Nginx logs at once aesthetically, in stdout

Tags: nginx, logging, stdout

This is how I display all Nginx logs at once aesthetically (with headings and spacing), in stdout, for comfortable debugging.

Input:

```
printf '\n\n General: \n\n'; nginx -t; printf '\n\n Access: \n\n'; tail /var/log/nginx/access.log; printf '\n\n Errors: \n\n'; tail /var/log/nginx/error.log
```

Output:

```
 General:

     ...

 Access:

     ...

 Errors:

     ...
```

As you can see, the command is quite long or "heavy".

Is there a shorter (formal?) way to achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see any way to make the *commands* shorter, but you can wrap them in a [bash function](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/functions.html) that you can execute later using the function name rather than pasting (or typing!) that command again.

For instance, you could put a function in your `.bashrc` like:

```
nginxlogs () {
    printf '\n\n General: \n\n'
    nginx -t
    printf '\n\n Access: \n\n'
    tail /var/log/nginx/access.log
    printf '\n\n Errors: \n\n'
    tail /var/log/nginx/error.log
}
```

Now when you run `nginxlogs` from your bash shell, everything will appear.